# How to display a profile picture in a MERN stack app without it looking weird?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer, react-dropzone

I am building a mern-stack application and want the user to have a profile pic , so I created an API using multer and node.js for uploading the image in the backend and react dropZone in the frontend . and i am displaying the picture in the profile vue but its looking a little weird to fit the space so I tried some resizing tools like react-image-file-resize but its not doing anything. I'll attach a picture to demonstrate .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3p3D.png)
is there another way to fix the image .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUClJ.png)

Comment: Image might look Ok to someone. Tell us what is the problem

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I am not OP

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz its like trying to fit the image to the space provided to display the image .  so its messing with its height and width or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of different ways of handling image resizing. Have you thought about handling it with just css? something like `object-fit: cover;` might help you out. Or just have a width and no height. Image resizing/cropping/preview-generation/resolution/etc. Can be a real pain.

Comment: thank you it was fixed with messing around with css and object-fit : cover ; was key you're great

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an issue with your react code. While a user upload their profile, add a restriction on the resolution of the photo. You could either process the image to a suitable resolution by your self or let the user upload the required resolution in the first place.

To crop the image to a desired resolution there are Open Source javascript plugins. I came across this while googling.

[Croppie - a simple javascript image cropper](https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/)

Then where you display the image, add a css restriction for the `img` tag to be a specific size, such as 100px by 100px.

Or else have the restriction right on the `img` tag itself.

`<img src='profile.jpg' width="50" height="50" className='profile-pic'>`